# Permutations and combinations - number of solutions

Tags: permutations

**Question:**

> Find the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3 = 51$ for $x_1,x_2,x_3$ being odd numbers

Not sure how I would even begin this question. It would be simple except for the condition given of being odd numbers. Please help by giving a hint to get started.

Comment: I changed sum + to , as I strongly assumed this was the intent. If not please clarify what was meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution $x_i=2y_i+1$ would help; then you need to find the number of solutions to this equation for nonnegative integers.

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement of $x_1,x_2,$ and $x_3$ is just that they are odd integers, then there are infinitely many solutions (e.g. $x_1=51, x_2=2n+1, x_3=-2n-1$). If, as is more likely, the requirement is that they are *positive* odd numbers, then there are a finite number of solutions.

There are $25$ possibilities for $x_1$: the odd numbers between $1$ and $49$, inclusive.

Given the value of $x_1$, $x_2$ can be any of the odd numbers between $1$ and $50-x_1$, inclusive. For each of the $25$ choices for $x_1$, the number of choices for $x_2$ is thus $$\frac{51-x_1}{2}$$

Given $x_1$ and $x_2$, $x_3$ is fixed. Thus we want to evaluate the sum

$$\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{x_1 \text{odd} \\ 1 \leq x_1 \leq 49}} \frac{51-x_1}{2}$$

This is equivalent to

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{25} \frac{51-(2k-1)}{2} &=\sum_{k=1}^{25} \frac{52-2k}{2}\\
&=25 \cdot 26 - \sum_{k=1}^{25} k\\\\
&=25(26-13)\\ \\
&=\boxed{325}
\end{align}